# (C++) When a function return data like class or struct, I want to return a error or false data

Tags: c++, return

I'm a newbie studying computer structure...

In this case

```
class Node{
   private:
      int data;
   public:
      Node(int num);
      int AddNum(int num);
}

Node::Node(int num) : data(num) {   }
int::int AddNum(int num)
{
   if(data + num > 10)
      return num;
   else
      return false; // this point!!
}
```

How can I deliver a sign of fail or error??

Thank you for reading my horrible english sentence.. i'm still learning english
i can read english well but,,, writing skill is terrible :(

have a nice day~

Comment: There are all sorts of ways. Without knowing your specific requirements (as distinct from the type of solution you've asked for) it's impossible to advise on what options are suitable. A simple way is to add a member to the struct/class named (say) `is_valid`, set that member in your function as needed, and document that the caller should check it.   A more intrusive way, generally only used if the error is critical so the user needs to be FORCED to deal with the cause, is to throw an exception.  And, BTW, `int::int` is not valid C++.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error

Answer (score 3):

You can use an [std::optional](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional). Make sure C++17 support is enabled in your compiler. If you're using GCC or Clang, that means add `-std=c++17` to your compiler flags (or `-std=c++1z` in older versions of GCC/Clang).

```
#include <optional>

class Node {
private:
    int data;

public:
    Node(int num);
    std::optional<int> AddNum(int num);
};

Node::Node(int num) : data(num) {}

std::optional<int> Node::AddNum(const int num)
{
    if (data + num > 10) {
        return num;
    }
    // Returns a default-constructed optional, which is empty.
    return {};
}
```

When calling `AddNum()`, you must check whether the returned optional is empty:

```
auto result = some_node.AddNum(some_number);
if (result) {
    // OK.
    std::cout << "the result is: " << *result;
} else {
    // Error. No result.
}
```

To get the value from an optional, you can use the `*` operator on it like you would with a pointer. Alternatively, you can use the `value()` member function instead:

```
std::cout << "the result is: " << result.value();
```

If you try to get a value from an empty optional, a runtime exception will be thrown.

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!!!!!!! i used it and works!!    when i asked this question in korean, people doesn't understand even if i'm korean..

Answer (score 2):

The function `AddNum` returns `int` so you can't return a `bool`. So you have a few options in this case:

1. Change the function to return a `bool` indicating success or failure, and pass the result back through an argument by reference. For example:

```
bool Node::AddNum(int num, int& result)
{
   if (condition)
   {
       result = num;
       return true;
   }
   else
   {
       result = 0;
       return false;
   }
}
```

And you would call the function thusly:

```
Node n;
int result;
bool success = n.AddNum(num, result);
```

2. Throw an exception, although sometimes this is frowned upon depending on the circumstances:

```
int Node::AddNum(int num)
{
   if (condition)
   {
       return num;
   }
   else
   {
       throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid argument");
   }
}

Of course the caller would need to handle the exception.
```

Comment: Thank you for your good advisement !    actually, i'm familiar with this solution than upper.. cuz i know little about c++ stl...   i have to study more and more

Answer (score 1):

You can return a `std::pair` or a union wrapped in structure or a custom structure or raise exception.

```
//Using pair. If first element is true, only then 
//second element hold meaning
int::int AddNum(int num)
{
   if(data + num > 10)
      return make_pair(true, num);
   else
      return make_pair(false, -1);
}
```